# Return value from fs.readdir()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a function:

```
function checkInitialFolderExistence() {
    fs.readdir(INITIAL_FOLDER_PATH, (err, files) => {
        if(err) {
            ... do something
            return false;
        } else {
            ... do something
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

How can I return a boolean value from the `fs.readdir` callback?

```
let initialFolderExists = await checkInitialFolderExistence();
console.log('initialFolderExists ' + initialFolderExists); // Returns 'undefined'
```